# Photo Sphere Viewer on React pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, photosphere, photosphereviewer

I am trying to implement Photo Sphere Viewer on my React Component, i already did it with Google Maps API and it worked fine, but i'm using the same technique, no results. If is there any other option to implement 360 Photo Viewer on React (Already used Pannellum, didn't like it, didn't worked) i'm open to suggestions.

https://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org/

i got the html code from: https://github.com/JeremyHeleine/Photo-Sphere-Viewer/blob/master/examples/example.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Photo Sphere Viewer</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="./three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./photo-sphere-viewer.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>

    <script>
        var div = document.getElementById('container');
        var PSV = new PhotoSphereViewer({
                panorama: 'http://tassedecafe.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/parc-saint-pierre-amiens.jpg',
                container: div,
                time_anim: 3000,
                navbar: true,
                navbar_style: {
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(58, 67, 77, 0.7)'
                },
            });
    </script>
</body>
```

---

```
*import React from 'react'; 
import '../../index.css';


class ShperePanel extends React.Component{

    componentDidMount() {
        this.renderSphere();
      }

    renderSphere = () => {
        loadScript('photo-sphere-viewer.min.js');
        loadScript('three.min.js');


        window.initSphere = this.initSphere;

      }
      initSphere = () => {
        const PVS = new window.PhotoSphereViewer({ 
        container: document.getElementByid('viewer'),
        panorama: 'http://tassedecafe.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/parc-saint-pierre-amiens.jpg',
        time_anim: 3000,
        navbar: true,
        navbar_style: {
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(58, 67, 77, 0.7)'
        }
    })
      }
render(){
    return(
    <div id="viewer"> </div>
    );
}

}
export default ShperePanel

function loadScript(url) {
    var index = window.document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    var script = window.document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true;
    index.parentNode.insertBefore(script, index); 
  }*
```

---

i would like to get something like this.

When i try to import the scripts(three.min.js, photo-sphere-viewer.min.js), with the "import from " syntax, directly, i get an error "PhotoSphereViewer" undefined.

Comment: Do you use webpack? If yes. Then also please show how do you import those packages.

Comment: Yes, i used create-react-app, those are installed and imported by default, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React 16.8 version with `useEffect` hook:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import PhotoSphereViewer from 'photo-sphere-viewer';

export default function Photo(props) {
  const sphereElementRef = React.createRef();
  const { src } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    const shperePlayerInstance = PhotoSphereViewer({
      container: sphereElementRef.current,
      panorama: src,
      ... // other options
    });    

    // unmount component instructions
    return () => {
      shperePlayerInstance.destroy();
    };
  }, [src]); // will only be called when the src prop gets updated


  return (
    <div ref={sphereElementRef}/>
  );
}
```

Comment: Let's wait a couple more days for reviews :)

Comment: Sorry for the ultra-late response Tiberiu, grateful with your help! Thank you!!! Its working fine!

Comment: Hey, no problem, would you also accept it as the answer since it's the newer and better fit for the question?

Comment: Sure! Are you able to see it now? Acoording to my screen it is now posted as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem and this is how I solve it:

```
npm install --save photo-sphere-viewer
```

and component look like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import * as Sphere from "photo-sphere-viewer";
import "photo-sphere-viewer/dist/photo-sphere-viewer.min.css"


export default class SphereComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.divStyle = {
          width: '100%',
          height: '600px'
        };
        this.sphereDiv = element => {
            this.photoSphereViewer = element;
        };
        this.sphereDiv.appendChild = (elem) => {
            this.subDiv.appendChild(elem)
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const PVS = Sphere({
            parent: this,
            container: this.sphereDiv,
            panorama: "https://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org/assets/Bryce-Canyon-National-Park-Mark-Doliner.jpg",
            navbar: [
                'autorotate',
                'zoom',
                'fullscreen'
            ]
        })
    }

    render() {
        return <div style={this.divStyle} ref={this.sphereDiv} id="viewer"><div ref={node => this.subDiv = node} style={this.divStyle}></div></div>
    }
}
```

That's it.

Comment: How do you cleanup in componentWillUnmount?

Comment: You must use this.photoSphereViewer (HTML Element) as container, not this.sphereDiv (Ref callback). You can call the "destroy" method on the PVS variable to destroy the viewer on unmount. Also "parent" is not a supported option.